# Atom/RSS feeds on Github Issues?

Tags: github

I've been using Google Code and basically everything has an individual RSS feed there.  Now I'm trying to migrate over to Github and find the equivalent.  I've found the URL for all commits https://github.com/ORG/PROJECT/commits/master.atom but now I'd like to get some other RSS feeds, most importantly the recent updates to issues - does any such feed exist?

Are there other RSS feeds for projects that can be accessed (Ex: Changes to the wiki)?

Is there a way to make the private feeds public?

Comment: For a project specific "feed", it might worth using [GitHub's webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) for realtime updates.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just solved this issue for one of my repos and imported [GitHub](https://github.com) [feed](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) items into my [drupal](http://drupal.org/) site.

I had originally created a feed of only commits using the URL convention:

```
https://github.com/ORG/PROJECT/commits/master.atom
```

but I also wanted a feed of GitHub-Issues and updates to Issues.

GitHub appears to now support an "everything" feed with the following convention:

```
https://github.com/username.private.actor.atom?token=somehextoken
```

Where `somehextoken` is replaced with a token relevant to your account.

You can get his feed+token URL automatically from GitHub using the following steps:

1. Login to your [GitHub account](https://github.com)
2. Go to the following page:

   https://github.com/dashboard/ (updated 2013-09)
3. Click on the `News Feed` button with feed-icon in the top right of the page.
4. This will take you to a feed [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) page. Copy the URL form your browser and paste where needed.
5. Filter the feed to your needs. The feed itself appears to include Issues updates and other details from all of the repos connected to your account. In my case, I just used a standard text filter to grab just the feed elements with `MyAcct/MyRepo1` in their title.

Note that this question is related to a [similar question in the web-apps stack exchange site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20535/on-github-is-there-anyway-to-view-newsfeed-timeline-for-a-specific-repository)

Comment: The feed from github.com/dashboard is misleading. While the dashboard displays activity for repos you are watching, the linked feed is for _your_ activity. If you want to get the feed for the repos you are watching, grab it from github.com (after logging in) or remove ".actor" part from the feed in the instructions above.

Comment: @cept0 it is better practice to provide an update or clarification about what has changed, rather than downvote an answer that was clearly useful prior to an API change. Maybe someone else wants to help you solve this, but I'm not feeling so motivated after receiving your "-2".

Comment: @PaulMcMurdie Does it still work? I tried with the given url & access-token generated from settings page but url shows an empty page.(?) I can access my own activity from `http:/github.com/username.atom` but how to access the feed of all watching repos (news feed)?

Comment: I've made an app called Pull Feed for keeping track of repositories via an atom feed: http://pullfeed.co. It might suit your needs!

Comment: @EdwardLoveall could Pull Feed work with organization-owned repositories?

Comment: It can't work with private repos, but organization repos should be fine. If you needed private repos it's opensource and could be deployed privately with a github api token.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the RSS feeds for a repository, you first have to **watch** the repository you're interested in. After *watching* it, head over to `https://github.com` and you should see *news* items for *all* your repositories start flowing in, as and when they happen.

Now if you need to use an external RSS reader (or similar), you should find a `News Feed` link on the main GitHub page that will take you to an aggregated RSS feed of any and all interesting things happening in your *watched* repositories. This will include information like pull requests, new issues, wiki changes, and so on.

Comment: I don't think this is quite upto it. I'm having the same issue, and while I can get a feed of my aggregated repositories, I'm struggling to get a feed of the one repo I'm interested in building a widget for.

Comment: How does this allow the user to filter only 'Issues' and not every single commit?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the page source, you'll see a link like:

```
   <link href="https://github.com/org/repo/releases.atom?token=TOKEN" rel="alternate" title="repo Release Notes" type="application/atom+xml" />
```

Unless I'm mistaken, that (including the token) is your public URL.

Answer (score -4):

Take a look at https://github.com/YannBenigot/GHTrendingRSS

> GitHub trending RSS feeds
>
> Small Google AppEngine application to provide RSS feeds for the GitHub
>   trending page.
>
> The application is available and deployed here:
>   http://ghtrendingrss.appspot.com/

Comment: Links are broken.